# Die puzzle with probability

Tags: probability

I have basic understanding of probability but I couldn't get following question. Please help me to get it.

There are $n$ dice each with $m$ faces numbered from $1$ to $m$. Given a number $x$, find out the probability that the sum of all numbers obtained from the $n$ dice in a trial is greater than $x$.

Answer (score 1):

- **Fact**: [Probability generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) (pgf) for the score of one die is $$\mathcal{P}(z) = \frac{1}{m} \left(z+z^2+\cdots+z^{m}\right) = \frac{z}{m} \frac{1-z^{m}}{1-z}$$
- **Fact**: The pgf of the total score (*assuming* independence of scores) $X$ is $\left(\mathcal{P}(z)\right)^n$.
- **Fact**: The generating function for the sequence $\mathbb{P}(X>k)$ is $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n \cdot m} z^k \mathbb{P}(X>k) = \frac{1- \left(\mathcal{P}(z)\right)^n}{1-z}$$

Thus the answer to your question is
$$
     \mathbb{P}(X>k) = [z^k] \frac{1-\left(\frac{z}{m} \frac{1-z^{m}}{1-z}\right)^n}{1-z}
$$

A good reference on the subject is the book "[*Problems and Snapshots from the World of Probability*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387941614)" by Blom, Holst and Sandell. See section 4.6 on page 39.

---

Here is numerical confirmation in *Mathematica*:

[image]